# What are tools available in Linux to create Virtual Hard drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a Lenovo Ideapad laptop and I am using Virtual Box for running Ubuntu on top of Windows 10 OS. I was wondering what are the tools available in Linux to create a Virtual Hard Drive for Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and explain what you mean by "virtual hard drive"? If you mean the drive in the virtual machine where the guest OS is installed, that is created in VirtualBox itself.

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/creating-virtual-disks-using-linux-command-line)? QEMU can also create virtual disks, for example.